# 11.04 won't boot all the way - unusable

Tags: 11.04, boot, troubleshooting

I'm new to ubuntu/linux and need some trouble shooting help. I setup 11.04 with zoneminder, it worked great for a few weeks and now it seems to boot fine but I'm unable to use anything.  runs very slow and when I open applications or windows they are not working. eg. I open a terminal window and it's just gray but never gets me to a prompt, firefox opens to a blank white window as does system monitor and everything else.

is there a bootup "safemode" or "restore point" option? ideas how to trouble shoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Video card? Ctrl+Alt+F1 and run: lspci | grep VGA

Comment: 1:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RS880 Radeon HD 4200.

Comment: Not to familiar with Radeon. Are you using the open source driver? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards